# Loading multiple images memory issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, uiimageview

I am having issues loading multiple images. My app was crashing because I was loading too many images. I tried to add some smart loading but that doesn't fix the problem. I changed the image imagenamed method to load everything using

```
UIImage *newImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
```

then adding it to an array and then releasing everything if i do receive a memory warning or when i change viewcontroller.

The issue arises due to the fact that the did receive memory warning never occurs and the app just throws a:

Program received signal:  “0”.

Now, anyone got any suggestions? i.e should i use calayers instead of uiimageviews? Will that make any difference? Instruments doesn't show any major leaks and the heap never goes beyond 2-3 mb.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]???

Comment: Yup this is what i am using .

Comment: Are you sure that memory is your problem? Not an exception or a BAD_ACCESS? What happens when you simulate a memory warning?

Comment: nothing happens. it is not a badaccess 100%

Answer (score 0):

Try to nil your imageViews before you release.
Also before assign the images nil your imageviews so that if you have a image previously in that imageview that memory will be cleared.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i will try that but does setting nil forces the image to cleared from memory ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't load all the Images at the same time. Load images according to the requirement. Post your code in this thread. You are right your code is leaking memory somewhere.

Comment: This is what i am doing but one page needs to show 10 image and they are 2mb + , I already told the client to  reduce those and have thumbnails instead.

Comment: Yes. that's right. Because of image size also you can face this problem.